# Gyroscope Problem

Tags: microcontroller, gyro

I am working at a project which requires to determine the roll of a device. I studied the method through I can do this and I find that an IMU (Inertial Measurement Unit) could help me. I started with the gyro but I do not know sure if it works correctly. Gyro starts to drift too quickly, if I roll in one direction the gyro angle is about 10 degrees shifted. I am using the STM [L3GD20](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00036465.pdf) gyro module. If somebody could explain me if this is normal I will appreciate.

Comment: How about proper data sheet links?

Comment: https://www.google.ro/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00036465.pdf&ved=0CCQQFjAAahUKEwicutD6qJjIAhVBORQKHZfvDYw&usg=AFQjCNEfMS7XqSqRoMnpRZeUJnq3dzR78g&sig2=lKhWnIxhDDl45potq1-gzw  Sorry i forgot ..

Comment: I'd use the accelerometer instead of the gyro

Comment: If the error occurs the INSTANT you move it, you may not be sampling fast enough, or there is a low-pass filter involved that is slowing down the signal.

Comment: @StefanMerfu is it possible to add some more technical details as to the steps you took to solve the problem, micro-controller your using and section of code.

Comment: Well, i am using the STM32F401 microcontroller, the library is written by me in the KEIL UVision is an IDE for STM family and other more.The communication worked perfectly using SPI.The problem appears when i start to integrate the value over time.I also mention that i calibrated the device first and then use.I "sample" at 10 mS(the reading takes about 3.75 uS  measured with my oscilloscope, so this will not affect the integration interval).I want to know if the bias(drift) of gyro is normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to add a bit more explanation to the why's of using a gyro vs accelerometer for orientation: A gyro gives rotation rate, so to get orientation, we have to integrate:

orientation = Integrate(gyro_data, dt) + C

The C tells us we never get absolute orientation, only relative orientation. With the accelerometer, at least we get an absolute orientation with respect to gravity.

The integration tells us that our noise will accumulate over time, and our value for orientation will become worse as time goes on. We do *not* need to integrate to get orientation from accelerometer. Even if our gyro has less noise than our accelerometer, it might still make sense to use the accelerometer. It depends on the relative noise levels and how long you plan to sample.

Where the gyro shines is during dynamic motion of the device. We can use the combination of the gyro and accelerometer to better distinguish linear motion from change in orientation.

Comment: Thank you for proper answear ! A complementary filter will work ?

Comment: Complementary filter is good, especially if you're performing the calculations on an embedded system.

Comment: I'm using the STM32F4 a 32bits microcontroller with FPU unit and 84MHx.

Comment: Sounds like you should be good.

Comment: The accelerometer gives you absolute orientation in the absence of translational or centripetal acceleration.

Answer (score 2):

As [Scott Seidman](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/11684/scott-seidman) suggested I would recommend using an accelerometer to determine the roll of a device. Below are the equation I used with the [ADXL345](http://www.analog.com/en/products/mems/mems-accelerometers/adxl345.html) accelerometer from Analog devices.

```
accelerationX = (signed int)(((signed int)rawData_X) * 3.9);
accelerationY = (signed int)(((signed int)rawData_Y) * 3.9);
accelerationZ = (signed int)(((signed int)rawData_Z) * 3.9);
pitch = 180 * atan (accelerationX/sqrt(accelerationY*accelerationY + accelerationZ*accelerationZ))/M_PI;
roll = 180 * atan (accelerationY/sqrt(accelerationX*accelerationX + accelerationZ*accelerationZ))/M_PI;
```

Complete source code I used for the project can be found [here](https://github.com/mahengunawardena/BeagleboneBlack_I2C_ADXL345/blob/master/ADXL345Accelerometer.cpp). You are more than welcome to fork the code.

The response to [Calculating pitch, yaw, and roll from mag, acc, and gyro data](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3348/calculating-pitch-yaw-and-roll-from-mag-acc-and-gyro-data) has more details that you might find useful. Also below are references that you might find useful.

---

**References:**

- [Beaglebone black ADXL345 source code](https://github.com/mahengunawardena/BeagleboneBlack_I2C_ADXL345/blob/master/ADXL345Accelerometer.cpp)
- [Adxl345 Beaglebone black Embedded QT Demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bd7ULY1frA4)
- [Arduino IMU: Pitch & Roll from an Accelerometer](http://theccontinuum.com/2012/09/24/arduino-imu-pitch-roll-from-accelerometer/)
- [Calculating pitch, yaw, and roll from mag, acc, and gyro data](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/3350/110)
- [ADXL345 - Triple-Axis Accelerometer (+-2g/4g/8g/16g) w/ I2C/SPI](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1231)
- [How do I conduct an experimental modal analysis with a three-axis accelerometer?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5365/how-do-i-conduct-an-experimental-modal-analysis-with-a-three-axis-accelerometer)

Comment: Thank you for response, my question is accelerometer is not a noise device ? I want to determine this angle    with 1 degree accuracy, that is why i choose to use an accelerometer and a gyroscope.

Comment: @StefanMerfu, I have not work on a Gyro in ages. Also I am not too familiar with the L3GD20 Gyro module. I used the ADXL345 accelrometer to measure roll. I hope you can find infomation that will help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Look at page 9, table 2.1 - "Mechanical characteristics". For a 250 degree/sec unit, zero can be off by +/- 10 degree/sec, so you have to determine level, then provide an offset. This will then vary with temperature, but the unit also provides a temperature reading, and this will help.

It's not clear what your 10 degrees refers to. Are you saying that a rotation in one (mechanical) axis gives a reading in one of the non-rotating axes of about 10% of the valid axis? If so, this is likely caused by a non-precision fixture which is providing rotation in an axis other than you think.

At any rate, these units have a considerable drift rate (and the fast units are even worse), but that's what you get for the money. Gyros with much lower drifts are available, but they are bigger and much more expensive. Providing the proper offset adjustment is up to you.

Comment: What i am trying to say is that after i calibrated my device ( i read 100 times the specific axis and make an average of the values) , i transform my raw values to angles by dividing to value from datasheet and integrate at 10 mS interval which gives me the angle the value will drift easily to 50 degrees in 10-20 seconds and if i rotate the device let's say that now we have 0 degrees and rotate to 60 degrees when i m going the device back to 0 degrees will show me 15 degrees or more depend on how fast i rotated the device.

Comment: That doesn't seem to make much sense. Set the unit level. Take (let's say) 100 readings and take the average. Now subtract this from each reading, and the average should be zero. Keep adjusting until you get an average zero rate at zero degrees. Now rotate 60 degrees and back again. Are the new readings averaging zero?

Comment: It drifts a little bit every time i roll

Comment: Don't tease. How much is a little? What is your full scale, and how many counts of drift?

Comment: Well,I use the lowest range +-250dps,if i rotate to 50 degrees and i go back to 0 degrees the output will be -1.2 degrees.

Comment: So the gyro doesn't drift. Rather, you're getting different integrated angles depending on which way you rotate, right? When the gyro isn't moving, what sort of integrator drift rates are you getting?

Comment: Yeah , you are right , when i integrate the value will go slowly up with about 0.01 even after i calibrate

Comment: So you need to create a table of drift rates vs temperature, then use the reported temperature to provide a running correction. Next, just how precise is your mechanical fixture? 1 degree isn't much. And how long does your back and forth rotation take? And what happens to the temperature while it does?

Comment: Where i did the test the temperture was 16 degrees, i didn't test with another temperture.

Comment: I don't mean external temperature. I mean the unit temperature as reported by the gyro. And if you weren't paying attention, it's time you started.

Comment: I know the 16 degrees was taken from gyro module